# Is Reviewer badge removed from list of badges?

Tags: support

In my profile in stackoverflow, I don't see `Reviewer` badge in `Available`. When I clicked on `silver` tag, I still don't see it. But when I visited [Badges](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges), I see it is present. Is it a bug or I'm missing something?

[image]

Comment: No, you are only looking in the badges you haven't gotten yet

Comment: I don't believe the progress tracker contains badges you can earn multiple times.

Comment: @michaelpri I've not received `Reviewer` badge. So, it should be there

Comment: @animuson I guess, you are right, it is possible :)